# How to add keyword to bookmark in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

In Firefox, I had bookmarks with keywords, so I could easily search for stuff. When I imported these bookmarks to Chrome - keywords still work. But when adding new bookmark, I can't find a way to define its keyword.

Is it possible to add keyword to bookmark in Chrome? If yes, how?

Comment: Could you give an example of how and where you use those keywords?. Because can do `shift+ctrl+o` to open the bookmarks manager which has a search box. You can also replace the name of the bookmark. Also the omnibox itself suggests from your bookmarks.

Comment: Kayword is a special word that can be used for accessing given bookmark. It can also modify URL. Example on usage in Firefox can be found in here: http://www.depesz.com/2007/09/26/easy-access-to-postgresql-documentation-from-firefox/

Answer (score 12):

If you don't mind an alternative solution, what you mentioned looks a lot like custom search engines on Chrome.

[Look here](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95653)

And [this is something I did](https://plus.google.com/104650996836235748600/posts/fNL5Awv6WTQ) using custom search engines.

Using Omnibox and the multiple search engines provided by Chrome, you can add, for example a custom one for the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/) (If it wasn't added automatically), just like the one in the picture below, with a nice and short **keyword**. In my case `aw`.

[image: **Let me know if the image is not displayed correctly here**]

So now, each time I want to search something on the ArchWiki, I just go to the omnibox, type aw and then hit tab (or space) and the custom search engine switches temporarily to ArchWiki, allowing me to quickly search directly there and even takes me to the appropriate page if the term is accurate enough.

// If you are wondering how the custom ArchWiki ended up in the top box, it's because I accidentally made it the default search engine.

Comment: The fact that it doesn't sync is a problem, but I can live with it. Thanks.

Comment: In fact it does sync, looks like in 1 of the latests updates, they fixed that. However I'm using the Version 26, Dev channel.

Comment: This is exactly how keywords works in Firefox.