# Add a Keyword for this Search

Tags: google-chrome, search, keyword

There is a feature I use a lot on Firefox which is:

- Right click on an input field
- Add a Keyword for this Search...

This allows me to easily send request like "shop ID 12345" directly in the URL bar instead of having to go through the actual search field.

However, I have to use Chrome at work and I can't find a similar feature.

Is there a way to achieve that on Chrome?

I tried using the custom search feature but it requires an URL + parameter (%s) and that can't work in my case since my requests don't go through an URL.

Edit: I'm okay with extensions if needed.

Answer (score 8):

See [here](https://superuser.com/a/540083/513400).

In `settings > Search Engines` you can add keywords to the Omnibox (Chrome's URL bar). These keywords, when typed into the Omnibox, let your search the site. To see an example of this, Any up-to-date chrome will have a "keyword" for "google.com". Go to the Omnibox and start typing "google" and it should ask you to `press tab to search Google`. The same thing applies when you add your own "Keyword".

Comment: Nope, as I said this doesn't work because it requires a URL + parameter. In my case, it has to reference an input field in a web page (just like Firefox does with this specific feature).

Comment: You can make your keyword anything, so it doesn't have to be "google.com" you could make it "g". Then entering g and pressing tab will allow you to search the page, with the keyword "g" assigned to it

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue.I did not know how to figure the URL parameters. I tried it with dictionary on `www.slovnik.cz`. When I typed text into edit box and hit enter the browser would not show parameters in URL - I still saw just `www.slovnik.cz`. What I did was I used firefox, right click on editBox and choosed "add a keyword for this search". Then I used it and firefox shows the complete URL request. So For example I add keyword "en" then I typed "en hippopotamus" and in firefox URL appeared:

```
http://www.slovnik.cz/bin/mld.fpl?vcb=hippopotamus&dictdir=encz.en&lines=30&js=1
```

Then I just changed "hippopotamus" for %s. To fill it in chrome is easy - right click on chrome URL edit box->"edit search engine" and fill URL. Eg.:

```
http://www.slovnik.cz/bin/mld.fpl?vcb=%s&dictdir=encz.en&lines=30&js=1
```

and it works :)